# What are the correct permissions for service account to run databasemail?

Tags: sql-server-2005, email

I setup database mail on a SQL Server 2005 instance and kept getting this log message whenever an email was tried:

```
Message
1) Exception Information

Exception Type: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Objects.AccountGetAccount(Int32)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: DatabaseMailEngine
```

After checking to make sure my setup was correct, I tried adding the service account user to the sysadmin group, which resolved the problem.

But I'd like to know if that's necessary, or if the particular permissions issue was simply blanketed by the sysadmin role. Is there some more granular permission that I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is something less drastic than `sysadmin`!

To use database mail the user must be a user in the `msdb` database and a member of the `DatabaseMailUserRole` database role within `msdb`.

```
USE msdb
CREATE USER MailUser FOR LOGIN MailUser
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename='DatabaseMailUserRole', @membername='MailUser'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. That was already done, otherwise the mail wouldn't even get queued. The error message in my original post was reported under the service account in the DB Mail log.